# assertResponseRedirects method with PHPUnit by passing the URI as a parameter

Tags: symfony, phpunit

Can someone explain to me why when I use the assertResponseRedirects method with PHPUnit by passing the URI as a parameter:

```
class UserControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testUnauthenticatedIsRedirected(): void
    {
        $this->client->request('GET', '/account');
        static::assertResponseRedirects('/login');
    }
}
```

I have this error:

```
Failed asserting that Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse Object &0000000044abc158000000000cda95f8 (
    'targetUrl' => 'http://localhost/login'
...
```

But if I put the absolute URL, the test works:

```
public function testUnauthenticatedIsRedirected(): void
{
    $this->client->request('GET', '/account');
    static::assertResponseRedirects('http://localhost/login');
}
```

Everyone puts the URI and it works, but not me... I'm on Symfony 5.2.1

Thank you in advance